# Using FontAwesome with Nativescript-Vue

Tags: nativescript, font-awesome, nativescript-vue

I'm just not succeeding in using FontAwesome icons in my Nativescript-Vue app. If I just want to use a regular icon, it works fine:

```
<Label col="0" text.decode="&#xf279;" class="fa"></Label>
```

But when I want a Solid (or I suppose any of the others), no love.

```
<Label col="0" text.decode="&#xf5da;" class="fa fas"></Label>
```

I've looked at so many instructions now that my eyes are crossed.
Today I upgraded to v5. But I don't thing I was able to get the solid ones to work before.

Comment: May I know why you are applying both fa and fas (assuming you have defined different font family in each class), you are suppose to apply only one? Can you post the definition of both classes if you still have the issue.

Comment: Manoj, I thought my older instructions had said to use both?

Comment: Anway, I am trying to use version 5, and the instructions here seem to imply that they define fas in the plugin, and that it is default? https://github.com/FortAwesome/vue-fontawesome#using-solid-icons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing I tried from the V5 instructions seemed to work. (Maybe someone can write explicit instructions for using in Nativescript-Vue.)

But, falling back to the old way, the simple

```
<Label col="0" text.decode="&#xf5da;" class="fas"></Label>
```

with

```
.fas {
        font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free", "fa-solid-900";
    }
```

And, I must have somehow been interupted when I first set this up, because `fa-solid-900` was not actually in my `[app.fonts][1]` folder. :-|

Not sure what all those fancy new packages I installed will do now.

Answer (score 3):

I work with Nativescript-Vue and I use [Nathan Walker](https://github.com/NathanWalker) plugin [nativescript-fonticon](https://github.com/NathanWalker/nativescript-fonticon). It works very fine with FontAwesome 5.

It's very easy to use.

1. Install the plugin:

   `npm install nativescript-fonticon --save`
2. Place font icon `.ttf` files in `app/fonts`

   `fa-brands-400.ttf
    fa-regular-400.ttf
    fa-solid-900.ttf`
3. Create base class (my css file is placed in  `assets/scss/global.scss`):

   `.fa,
    .far {
      font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free', 'fa-regular-400';
      font-weight: 400;
     }
    .fas {
      font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free', 'fa-solid-900';
      font-weight: 900;
     }
    .fab {
      font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free', 'fa-brands-400';
      font-weight: 400;
     }`
4. Copy css to `app` somewhere. I place my files in `assets\css` folder (I use minified format):

   `assets/css/all.min.css
    assets/css/brands.min.css
    assets/css/fontawesome.min.css
    assets/css/regular.min.css
    assets/css/solid.min.css`
5. Add and load the plugin in `main.js`

   `import { TNSFontIcon, fonticon } from 'nativescript-fonticon'`

   `// Load TNSFonticon
    TNSFontIcon.debug = true
    TNSFontIcon.paths = {
      fa: './assets/css/fontawesome.min.css',
      far: './assets/css/regular.min.css',
      fas: './assets/css/solid.min.css',
      fab: './assets/css/brand.min.css'
    }
    TNSFontIcon.loadCss()
    Vue.filter('fonticon', fonticon)`
6. Use the component in your code:

   `<Label class="fas" text="fa-chess-knight | fonticon"></Label>`

Comment: The above is VueJS and step 6 should actually be <Label class="fas" :text="'fa-chess-knight' | fonticon">